# Unable to access Instagram while running scripts via Jenkins

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

This code works fine when I run it in VS Code.  But when triggered through Jenkins, I get the Instagram splash page (screenshot) and it doesn't load the actual page.  I tried putting additional waits, tried in different browsers - no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  At this point, I am not really sure if it is a testcafe issue.

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe'

fixture`Feedback Test`
    .page`https://www.instagram.com/`

    .before(async t => {
    })

    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t.setTestSpeed(0.3)
        await t.maximizeWindow()
    })

test("Feedback", async t => {
    const instaHdr = Selector('.NXVPg.Szr5J').innerText
    await t.expect(instaHdr).contains('Instagram')
})
```

**Screenshot:**
[image: screenshot]

**Log: Jenkins Console Output:**

```
+ testcafe@1.8.7
+ testcafe-reporter-xunit@2.1.0
updated 2 packages and audited 1389 packages in 5.379s

5 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 73 vulnerabilities (41 low, 10 moderate, 22 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
[tcafe-sample] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/xc/tb86yjr146zfbtqkxr2t95q00000gn/T/jenkins735556649363166148.sh
+ /Users/xxxxx/node_modules/.bin/testcafe safari 'tests/**/*' -e --skip-js-errors -r xunit:res.xml
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Recording test results
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Log: Testcafe:**

```
1) Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified selector does not match any
      node in the DOM tree.

          > | Selector('.NXVPg.Szr5J')

         Browser: Safari 13.0.3 / macOS 10.14.6

            11 |        await t.maximizeWindow()
            12 |    })
            13 |
            14 |test("Feedback", async t => {
            15 |    const instaHdr = Selector('.NXVPg.Szr5J').innerText
          > 16 |    await t.expect(instaHdr).contains('Instagram')
            17 |})
            18 |
```

Comment: Can you provide logs of TestCafe tests' execution process from Jenkins? In the first place, we're interested in errors, if any. In addition, please specify the TestCafe version and browser version you are using.

Comment: Hi @aleks-pro: I was able to replicate the issue with a simpler example.  I have updated the code and logs in the question.  The versions are: Safari 13.0.3 / macOS 10.14.6 / Testcafe 1.8.7.

Comment: I just realized, I had Testcafe 1.8.4 in my local.  When i forced Jenkins to run on this version, it worked fine - npm install testcafe@1.8.4 testcafe-reporter-xunit.  So, i guess the issue is something specific to 1.8.7 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue. It occurs only in version 1.8.7. It looks like we already fixed a similar issue. Please try to run your tests in the `1.8.8-alpha.1` version. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  I don't see this issue in 1.8.8-alpha.1 but I ran into another issue where I got a blank page on clicking Instagram home button after logging in.  I am good with 1.8.4 version though.

Comment: @Janaaaa, feel free to create a thread on [our GitHub page](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues) regarding this issue.